# list() vs iterable unpacking in Python 3.5+

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterable, python-internals

Is there any practical difference between `list(iterable)` and `[*iterable]` in versions of Python that support the latter?

Comment: Corner case: it's possible to rebind the name `list` to something other than the built-in type, but you can't change the meaning of the `[*iterable]` syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list(x)` is a function, `[*x]` is an expression. You can reassign `list`, and make it do something else (but you shouldn't).

Talking about cPython, `b = list(a)` translates to this sequence of bytecodes:

```
LOAD_NAME                1 (list)
LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
CALL_FUNCTION            1
STORE_NAME               2 (b)
```

Instead, `c = [*a]` becomes:

```
LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
BUILD_LIST_UNPACK        1
STORE_NAME               3 (c)
```

so you can argue that `[*a]` *might* be slightly more efficient, but marginally so.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the standard library module [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to investigate the byte code generated by a function. In this case:

```
import dis

def call_list(x):
    return list(x)

def unpacking(x):
    return [*x]

dis.dis(call_list)
#   2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
#               2 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
#               4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#               6 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(unpacking)
#   2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
#               2 BUILD_LIST_UNPACK        1
#               4 RETURN_VALUE
```

So there is a difference and it is not only the loading of the globally defined name `list`, which does not need to happen with the unpacking. So it boils down to how the built-in `list` function is defined and what exactly `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK` does.

Note that both are actually a lot less code than writing a standard list comprehension for this:

```
def list_comp(x):
    return [a for a in x]

dis.dis(list_comp)
#   2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7f65356198a0, file "<ipython-input-46-dd71fb182ec7>", line 2>)
#               2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('list_comp.<locals>.<listcomp>')
#               4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
#               6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
#               8 GET_ITER
#              10 CALL_FUNCTION            1
#              12 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `[*iterable]` is unpacking, it accepts *assignment-like* syntax, unlike `list(iterable)`:

```
>>> [*[]] = []
>>> list([]) = []
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446168/and-assignments) (not useful though).

You can also use `list(sequence=iterable)`, i.e. with a key-word argument:

```
>>> list(sequence=[])
[]
```

Again [not useful](https://bugs.python.org/issue29695).

Comment: While one could write `[*var] = iterable` to mean `var = list(iterable)`, from readability standpoint it’s too much even to someone who’s no stranger to code golf. Also what an interesting symmetry between `[*var] = iterable` and `var = [*iterable]` (though broken in case of `(*var,) = iterable` and `var = (*iterable,)`).

Comment: @RomanOdaisky Indeed, `*lst, = (1,2,2); print(lst)` being the simplest I guess, though still not for recommended use

Comment: Actually, I found a valid use case for this: `for keys, [*rows] in itertools.groupby(...):`!

Answer (score 1):

There's always going to be some differences between two constructs that do the same thing. Thing is, I wouldn't say the differences in this case are actually *practical*. Both are expressions that take the iterable, iterate through it and then create a list out of it.

The contract is the same: input is an iterable output is a list populated by the iterables elements.

Yes, `list` can be rebound to a different name; `list(it)` is a function call while `[*it]` is a list display; `[*it]` is faster with smaller iterables but generally performs the same with larger ones. Heck, one could even throw in the fact that `[*it]` is three less keystrokes.

Are these practical though? Would I think of them when trying to get a list out of an iterable? Well, maybe the keystrokes in order to stay under 79 characters and get the linter to shut it up.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there’s a performance difference in CPython, where *[*a]* overallocates and *list()* doesn’t: [What causes [*a] to overallocate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549865/what-causes-a-to-overallocate)