# What causes [*a] to overallocate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, cpython, python-internals

Apparently `list(a)` doesn't overallocate, `[x for x in a]` overallocates at some points, and `[*a]` overallocates *all the time*?

[image: Sizes up to n=100]

Here are sizes n from 0 to 12 and the resulting sizes in bytes for the three methods:

```
0 56 56 56
1 64 88 88
2 72 88 96
3 80 88 104
4 88 88 112
5 96 120 120
6 104 120 128
7 112 120 136
8 120 120 152
9 128 184 184
10 136 184 192
11 144 184 200
12 152 184 208
```

Computed like this, [reproducable at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CoordinatedUnsungShockwave), using Python 3.**8**:

```
from sys import getsizeof

for n in range(13):
    a = [None] * n
    print(n, getsizeof(list(a)),
             getsizeof([x for x in a]),
             getsizeof([*a]))
```

**So: How does this work?** How does `[*a]` overallocate? Actually, what mechanism does it use to create the result list from the given input? Does it use an iterator over `a` and use something like `list.append`? Where is the source code?

([Colab with data and code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LOy2rb63wHZ2TSFrnoSlYXz1oOa1VkZ6) that produced the images.)

Zooming in to smaller n:

[image: Sizes up to n=40]

Zooming out to larger n:

[image: Sizes up to n=1000]

Comment: Fwiw, extending your test cases it would seem that the list comprehension behaves as writing a loop and appending each item to the list, while `[*a]` appears to behave as using `extend` on an empty list.

Comment: It might help to look at the byte code generated for each. `list(a)` operates entirely in C; it can allocate the internal buffer node by node as it iterates over `a`. `[x for x in a]` just uses `LIST_APPEND` a lot, so it follows the normal "overallocate a little, reallocate when necessary" pattern of a normal list. `[*a]` uses `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK`, which... I don't know what that does, other than apparently over-allocate all the time :)

Comment: Also, in Python 3.7, it appears that `list(a)` and `[*a]` are identical, and *both* overallocate compared to `[x for x in a]`, so... `sys.getsizeof` might not be the right tool to use here.

Comment: @chepner I think `sys.getsizeof` is the right tool, it just shows that `list(a)` used to overallocate. Actually [What’s New In Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) mentions it: *"The list constructor does not overallocate [...]"*.

Comment: @chepner: That [was a bug fixed in 3.8](https://bugs.python.org/issue33234); the constructor isn't supposed to overallocate.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`[*a]` [is internally doing the C equivalent of](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/ceval.c#L2703):

1. Make a new, empty `list`
2. Call `newlist.extend(a)`
3. Returns `list`.

So if you expand your test to:

```python
from sys import getsizeof

for n in range(13):
    a = [None] * n
    l = []
    l.extend(a)
    print(n, getsizeof(list(a)),
             getsizeof([x for x in a]),
             getsizeof([*a]),
             getsizeof(l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3BCsMgEETvfsUeNYRCya3QX@gPBA9C11Qwq@geTH7eRgvNLXOanXnsxI0/gaZabQor5C2DW2NIDAtydjsGK4QNCQgcQTK0oLxP6iHgkIEnzK9AqGEA6pFvkf7ZGxZGekuj@h2TI5Y0np@ld5mPWo0d@OsE5gJtvLRxoy@44ar1StX6BQ)

you'll see the results for `getsizeof([*a])` and `l = []; l.extend(a); getsizeof(l)` are the same.

This is usually the right thing to do; when `extend`ing you're usually expecting to add more later, and similarly for generalized unpacking, it's assumed that multiple things will be added one after the other. `[*a]` is not the normal case; Python assumes there are multiple items or iterables being added to the `list` (`[*a, b, c, *d]`), so overallocation saves work in the common case.

By contrast, a `list` constructed from a single, presized iterable (with `list()`) may not grow or shrink during use, and overallocating is premature until proven otherwise; [Python recently fixed a bug that made the constructor overallocate even for inputs with known size](https://bugs.python.org/issue33234).

As for `list` comprehensions, they're effectively equivalent to repeated `append`s, so you're seeing the final result of the normal overallocation growth pattern when adding an element at a time.

To be clear, none of this is a language guarantee. It's just how CPython implements it. The Python language spec is generally unconcerned with specific growth patterns in `list` (aside from guaranteeing amortized `O(1)` `append`s and `pop`s from the end). As noted in the comments, the specific implementation changes again in 3.9; while it won't affect `[*a]`, it could affect other cases where what used to be "build a temporary `tuple` of individual items and then `extend` with the `tuple`" now becomes multiple applications of `LIST_APPEND`, which can change when the overallocation occurs and what numbers go into the calculation.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I'd read the code before (which is why I knew this already). [This is the byte code handler for `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/ceval.c#L2703), it uses `_PyList_Extend` as the C equivalent of calling `extend` (just directly, rather than by method lookup). They combined it with the paths for building a `tuple` with unpacking; `tuple`s don't overallocate nicely for piecemeal building, so they always unpack to a `list` (to benefit from overallocation), and convert to `tuple` at the end when that's what was requested.

Comment: Note that this [apparently changes in 3.9](https://bugs.python.org/issue39320), where the construction is done with separate bytecodes (`BUILD_LIST`, `LIST_EXTEND` for each thing to unpack, `LIST_APPEND` for single items), instead of loading everything on the stack before building the whole `list` with a single byte code instruction (it allows the compiler to perform optimizations that the all-in-one instruction didn't allow, like implementing `[*a, b, *c]` as `LIST_EXTEND`, `LIST_APPEND`, `LIST_EXTEND` w/o needing to wrap `b` in a one-`tuple` to meet the requirements of `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK`).

Answer (score 18):

Full picture of *what* happens, building on the other answers and comments (especially [ShadowRanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60551320/1672429), which also explains *why* it's done like that).

Disassembling shows that `BUILD_LIST_UNPACK` gets used:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('[*a]')
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              2 BUILD_LIST_UNPACK        1
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

That's handled [in `ceval.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6b452ff97f70eca79ab956987cc04b6586feca00/Python/ceval.c#L2703), which builds an empty list and extends it (with `a`):

```
        case TARGET(BUILD_LIST_UNPACK): {
            ...
            PyObject *sum = PyList_New(0);
              ...
                none_val = _PyList_Extend((PyListObject *)sum, PEEK(i));
```

`_PyList_Extend` [uses](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/efc28bbbeee07867669dfbf49385d6a2147fe631/Objects/listobject.c#L959-L962) `list_extend`:

```
_PyList_Extend(PyListObject *self, PyObject *iterable)
{
    return list_extend(self, iterable);
}
```

Which [calls `list_resize` with the sum of the sizes](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/efc28bbbeee07867669dfbf49385d6a2147fe631/Objects/listobject.c#L861-L871):

```
list_extend(PyListObject *self, PyObject *iterable)
    ...
        n = PySequence_Fast_GET_SIZE(iterable);
        ...
        m = Py_SIZE(self);
        ...
        if (list_resize(self, m + n) < 0) {
```

And that [overallocates](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/efc28bbbeee07867669dfbf49385d6a2147fe631/Objects/listobject.c#L61) as follows:

```
list_resize(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t newsize)
{
  ...
    new_allocated = (size_t)newsize + (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
```

Let's check that. Compute the expected number of spots with the formula above, and compute the expected byte size by multiplying it with 8 (as I'm using 64-bit Python here) and adding an empty list's byte size (i.e., a list object's constant overhead):

```
from sys import getsizeof
for n in range(13):
    a = [None] * n
    expected_spots = n + (n >> 3) + (3 if n < 9 else 6)
    expected_bytesize = getsizeof([]) + expected_spots * 8
    real_bytesize = getsizeof([*a])
    print(n,
          expected_bytesize,
          real_bytesize,
          real_bytesize == expected_bytesize)
```

Output:

```
0 80 56 False
1 88 88 True
2 96 96 True
3 104 104 True
4 112 112 True
5 120 120 True
6 128 128 True
7 136 136 True
8 152 152 True
9 184 184 True
10 192 192 True
11 200 200 True
12 208 208 True
```

Matches except for `n = 0`, which `list_extend` actually [shortcuts](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/efc28bbbeee07867669dfbf49385d6a2147fe631/Objects/listobject.c#L862-L871), so actually that matches, too:

```
        if (n == 0) {
            ...
            Py_RETURN_NONE;
        }
        ...
        if (list_resize(self, m + n) < 0) {
```

Answer (score 8):

These are going to be implementation details of the CPython interpreter, and so may not be consistent across other interpreters.

That said, you can see where the comprehension and `list(a)` behaviors come in here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L36

Specifically for the comprehension:

```
 * The growth pattern is:  0, 4, 8, 16, 25, 35, 46, 58, 72, 88, ...
...

new_allocated = (size_t)newsize + (newsize >> 3) + (newsize < 9 ? 3 : 6);
```

Just below those lines, there is `list_preallocate_exact` which is used when calling `list(a)`.

Comment: `[*a]` isn't appending individual elements one at a time. It's got its own dedicated bytecode, that does bulk insertion via `extend`.

Comment: Gotcha - I guess I didn't dig far enough on that. Removed the section on `[*a]`