# Generating a list of numbers - which one is better in general?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
n=[n for n in range(10)]
print(n)

r=list(range(10))
print(r)

a=range(0,10)
print(list(a))
```

Is there any handful advantages of these particular notations?

Comment: All of them is almost same, but the last two are a little bit faster cus they are not using list compression.

Comment: I think it depends on situation. If you are wondering about performance, you can do it yourself with `timeit`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes \[\*a\] to overallocate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60549865/what-causes-a-to-overallocate)

Answer (score 3):

Python has a `timeit` module for quick benchmarks:

```
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("[n for n in range(10)]")
0.4846451000000229
>>> timeit.timeit("list(range(10))")
0.3175106840000126
>>>
```

Obviously, using `list()` is faster. It's also less verbose and the intent is clearer IMHO (list comprehensions are usually used to transform/filter iterables).

Answer (score 0):

Bruno already explained why list comprehensions might not be ideal, but I wanted to emphasize some difference between lists and ranges.

It's important to note that a `list` and a `range` have some different functionality and methods. So the answer to 'which one is better' depends on your application.

### Advantages of a range

A range is an iterable and doesn't have to keep all numbers in memory. Python for example has no issue with `range(int(1e20))`, but `list(range(int(1e20)))` will throw an error.

A range can also be queried much more efficiently. Compare the following code snippet:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("100 in numbers",setup='numbers=range(10000)')
0.1061642
>>> timeit("100 in numbers",setup='numbers=list(range(10000))')
1.2257957
```

For this case, a range is 10x faster to query, and this will difference will only increase for larger lists.

### Advantages of a list

The biggest difference is that a list can contain any type of objects. So if you want your numbers to be floats, then this is the easier solution.

Additionally, it allows you to append or delete single entries. So if you need some custom ordering of your numbers, then a list might be easier.