# list __sizeof__() result in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the list created in 3 different ways and the `__sizeof__()` method returns different values for each of them:

```
>>> l1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> print(l1.__sizeof__())
120
>>> l2 = list(i for i in range(10))
>>> print(l2.__sizeof__())
136
>>> l3 = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> print(l3.__sizeof__())
168
```

Does the way of creation impacts size calculation? My assumpion is that, the data structures should be the same.

Similar test for tuple returns the same size value:

```
>>> t1 = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> print(t1.__sizeof__())
104
>>>
>>> t2 = tuple(i for i in range(10))
>>> print(t2.__sizeof__())
104
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python generator objects: \_\_sizeof\_\_()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12477835/python-generator-objects-sizeof)

Comment: The proposed duplicate is not appropriate. This effect is from overallocating and trimming lists, since they must be prepared to change size. The dupe is about confusing size with length.

Comment: [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60549865/12671057), showing overallocations at different sizes

Comment: `__sizeof__` is an implementation detail of CPython, not part of the language. Unless you are hacking on CPython itself, you shouldn't care what it returns (or even if it is available.)